# Chmod all files and directories recursively to 666 under /usr

Tags: chmod, recursive

I want to make an chmod command that's recursively will apply the privilegies to all directoris under that.
Example:

chmod 666 /usr

I want that every directory under "/usr" turn into permissions to 666.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You surely don't want to make that change to `/usr`. There are good reasons that linux distributions set the permissions they do, and it is at your own peril to change them in such a drastic fashion.

Comment: To expound, the security ramifications of making this change are profound. Giving write access to all of `/usr`, well, you might as well walk around all day with your pants down.

Comment: Frankly, *If you can't figure out how to do this without asking us you've got no business doing it*. Please see the question I've marked this as a duplicate of for why this is a ***BAD IDEA***. If after reading and understanding that question and the answers you still think this is what you want, ask the question again in terms of a practical end goal rather than its current form, which is effectively "How to I wreck my system to the point where I have to reinstall it?"

Comment: Did `chmod -R 666 /usr` not provide the desired results?

Comment: No I won't chmod at /usr, it was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

First, please learn to read man pages:

```
$ man chmod
```

Partway down that page, you will see:

```
-R, --recursive
              change files and directories recursively
```

And there's your answer.

Comment: This was not an answer (the `man` for chmod is pages and pages long -- that's the point why OP is here). Here is the real answer:
`chmod 666 -R /usr`